# NGINX TCP Load balancer server port is not working

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I'm trying to configure nginx TCP Load balancing. I have 3 applicatios, running on 5001-5003 ports on different machine.

If I configure TCP load balancer as follows:

```
stream {
    upstream centos-01 {
        server 10.0.0.84:5001;
        server 10.0.0.84:5002;
        server 10.0.0.84:5003;
    }
    server {
        listen 5001;
        proxy_pass centos-01;
    }
}
```

Executing application by calling load_balancer_machine_ip:5001 works as expected. However, if I want nginx to listen to different port:

```
server {
    listen 9090;
    proxy_pass centos-01;
}
```

I get socket timeouts and it would seem as if nginx is not listening to this port (I'm quite frankly lost as to what the problem is).

Calling load_balancer_machine_ip:9090 produces socket timeout/not being able to connect.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you reloaded nginx after the change? Can you share the output of `sudo netstat -ntlp`?

Comment: Forgot to mention, this is on windows server machine. Yes I did. I switched back to 5001 and it was working again.

Comment: Not familiar with this OS but try [this tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/mullais/network/to-check-if-a-port-is-open).

Comment: Using netstat I can see that 9090 port is being listend to by nginx. And that port is opened from server (AWS in this case) same as 5001. Yet I can't connect to it with telnet.

Comment: What does the `nginx` error log shows?

Comment: No errors. Just `signal process started`

Comment: And what about the access log? Or maybe even [debugging the connection](http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html).

Comment: Access log does not log it. Maybe request does not even reach nginx and it's server issue. Though why would it work with other port (5001) then. Don't see any errors with debugging either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216406/discussion-between-yaron-and-crazysabbath).